# How to get a picture over a sphere in Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

How can i get a picture over a 3D-object in JavaFx Scene Builder.

I want to set the picture over a Javafx 3D Sphere, i have set the sphere in line filling because if i don't do this i can't even see the middle of my image.

[image]

Comment: On the document pane, drag your ImageView right below the sphere to change the order.

Comment: Do you want to add the image as a layer over the sphere (two different nodes)? Or do you want to add the image to the sphere (one single node, if you rotate it, the image moves with it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the left side of your SceneBuilder you can find "Document". You have a Hierarchy under Document. AnchorPane -> Pane .. -> Sphere. You have to drag your ImageView right below the sphere to change the order.

Hope that helped.